# What does "Expecting member declaration" mean?

Tags: kotlin

I am creating this class as part of a tutorial for Compose navigation.

```
sealed class Screens(val route: String) {
    object Screen1 : Screens( route: "screen1")
    object Screen2 : Screens( route: "screen2")
}
```

I am getting the error "Expecting member declaration". What does this error mean in simple terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should either be `Screens("screen1")` or (if you want to use named arguments) `Screens(route="screen1")`, with a `=`.

That error is because the syntax you're using (with the colon) is confusing the compiler, it doesn't make sense there

Comment: God bless!   I typed `route:` because thats what I saw in the video.  The `route:` does appear automatically from the IDE when I just typed "screen1".  ugh.

Comment: @dp38922 Oh yeah, those parameter hints are just the name of the parameter that appears in that position, it's not a code suggestion - they're nothing to do with Kotlin or its syntax! I have those turned off personally